# How to Substrat and multiply with case when condition

Tags: dplyr, tidyverse, data-wrangling, tidy, mutate

```
df1 <- data.frame(colname=c("A","B","C","D"),
          corr1=c(5500, 2400, 3900,5600),
          corr2=c(2.1944, 2.1936, 2.1934,2.1932),
          corr3=c(NA, 0.7934, NA ,NA),
          corr4=c(NA, 0.3104, NA, NA),
          corr5=c(NA, NA, 0.7933, NA)
                     )
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
```

For this data frame, I need to do substractions as shown below. I am missing something here.

```
df1<-df1 %>% 
  mutate(corr_final = case_when(
    colname == "C" ~ corr1*corr2 - (corr1*corr3[colname == "B"]),
    colname == "D" ~ corr1*corr2 - corr1*corr4[colname == "B"] - corr1*corr5[colname == "C"],
    .default = corr1*corr2
  ))
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: So... what is your question? Your `mutate` runs perfectly fine on my side.

Comment: sorry for not being clear. I need to subtract ( corr1*corr2 ) of column C from (corr1*corr3) of column B;  and  subtract ( corr1*corr2) of column D- (corr1*corr4) of column B - (corr1*corr5) of column C

Answer (score 0):

I have tried running the code, and it seemed that the error was related to the default option.

I tweaked the code to explicitly include three cases:

1. colname == "C"
2. colname == "D"
3. !colname %in% c("C", "D")

Also, according to your description, I have stated the location of corr1, i.e., [colname == "B"] and [colname == "C"].

```
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(corr_final = case_when(
    (colname == "C") ~ corr1 * corr2 - (corr1[colname == "B"] * corr3[colname == "B"]),
    (colname == "D") ~ corr1 * corr2 - (corr1[colname == "B"] * corr4[colname == "B"]) -
      (corr1[colname == "C"] * corr5[colname == "C"]),
    (!colname %in% c("C", "D")) ~ corr1 * corr2
  ))
```

Comment: yes, indeed. the error is related to the default option. code works now well.  thank you for noticing.